# append function is not working with the change function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have three select tags after choosing an option of each one those options will be the new option of a new select. I'm using change function. Problem one is when I use the change function the append function is not working with it.

here's my code

jquery// edited the code still APPEND is not working

```
 $('select[name="brand[]"]').change(function () {
 text= $(this).children("option").filter(":selected").text();
  value=$(this).val();
$('#select1').append(new Option(text, value));// the new select tag(not working)
       console.log(text,value);
      });
```

Comment: You are creating duplicate event listeners, by using the same global selector for making the change event

Comment: You keep getting `$('select[name="brand[]"]')`, which is a collection of Elements. Use `let t = $(this);` in your each loop instead.

Comment: That's not even needed.  You can just do the change event binding and ignore the outer each part.

Comment: I did, still the append function not working !!

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkhe8zw/ Provide a demo that demonstrates your problem

Comment: guys thanks for your efforts but look it works on https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkhe8zw/ 
 BUT not working on https://codepen.io/pen/ the same thing with my code!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```js
let value = '';
$('select[name="brand[]"]').change(function () {
 text= $(this).children("option").filter(":selected").text();
  value = $(this).val();
$('#select1').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+text+'</option>');
   console.log(text, value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="brand[]">
  <option value="one value">one text</option>
  <option value="two value">two text</option>
  <option value="three value">three text</option>
</select>

<select id="select1"></select>
```

Comment: guys thanks for your efforts but look it works on jsfiddle.net/5Lkhe8zw BUT not working on codepen.io/pen the same thing with my code!!!

Comment: Kindly open the link,  https://codepen.io/Em-An/pen/OJNvGeG - it works fine